# How can I make this php database class more secure?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

I'm using the following PHP MySQL database class. I'm curious as to what I could do to make it more secure. I'm happy with it so far, but without suggesting to "use PDO" what can I do to improve this currently?

```
    <?

    class DbConnector {

    public static function getInstance(){
   static $instance = null;
   if($instance === null){
      $instance = new DbConnector();
   }

   return $instance;
    }

    var $theQuery;
    var $link;

    function DbConnector() {

        $host = 'localhost';
        $db     = '';
        $user = '';
        $pass = '';

        // connect to the db
        $this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        mysql_select_db($db);
        register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));
    }

    function find($query) {
        $ret = mysql_query($query, $this->link);
        if (mysql_num_rows($ret) == 0)
            return array();
        $retArray = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret))
            $retArray[] = $row;

        return $retArray;
    }

    function insert($query) {
        $ret = mysql_query($query, $this->link);

        if (mysql_affected_rows() < 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    function query($query) {
        $this->theQuery = $query;
        return mysql_query($query, $this->link);
    }

    function fetchArray($result) {

        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }

    function close() {
        mysql_close($this->link);
    }

    function exists($query) {
        $ret = mysql_query($query, $this->link);
        if (mysql_num_rows($ret) == 0)
            return false;
    }

    function last_id($query) {
        return mysql_insert_id($query);
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can reasonably expect this class to do to be secure or insecure; it's just a wrapper around some common idioms that you're sick of typing. Since you're not interested in moving to PDO (why _not_ let the API handle all your quoting for you?) _you_ are still responsible for the entire safety of all your database queries, with or without some typing aids.

Comment: Given that query-strings will be provided externally (and you haven't shown where username/password are coming from), isn't this question somewhat redundant?

Comment: Are you only interested in security improvements, or improvements in general?

Comment: `but without suggesting to "use PDO"` --- any **real** reason to not use PDO?

Comment: @Radu both, actually. As for not using PDO, I don't really have a reason, other than I haven't worked with it much. I guess I could start working on a PDO class.

Comment: I never did understand why people built another class to abstract PDO... why not just use it directly?

Comment: @Brad, because there are still database specific things (like table and field name quoting) which are database specific and can be conveniently wrapped in your own DB specific classes.  Also, PDO implements only the most fundamental stuff; an ORM on top of it is rather convenient.

Comment: @bob suggesting PDO is the right thing to do here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use something that would automatically escape strings for you, you should at least provide an `escapeString($string)` method (which would call `mysql_real_escape_string()`) that you can use to escape strings when composing the query.

If you want to start using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) (highly recommended) then you will probably have different methods and won't need to include an escaping method.

As for general considerations:

- don't use `var`, but rather use `public`, `protected` or `private` (`var` has been deprecated as of PHP 5.0, and is currently an alias for `public`)
- the `__construct()` method is preferred instead of the method with the name of the class
- it would be better not to connect in the constructor, but rather only connect when you really need to connect in order to perform a query; a constructor should do as little as possible, and generally only initialize properties
- `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` will return `false` if they cannot do what they're supposed to; you should throw an exception if that happens and catch it where you use the class
- the `mysql_query()` call in the `find()` and `exists()` methods might return something other than a resource (`false` for example) so you should check for that before calling `mysql_num_rows()`
- if you're not using `$theQuery` at all, you should remove it
- if you want to have access to `$theQuery`, you should make it private and provide a `getQuery()` accssor method
- if you're setting the `$link` property to the resource returned by `mysql_connect()`, you should use that property in all your `mysql_*` calls, such as the one at `last_id()`
- you should make `$link` private (as a rule of thumb, all properties should be private or protected, and accessor methods should be provided when needed - read about the concept of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29))
- even though all methods are by default `public`, having an explicit `public` keyword before each of them will make things clearer

Comment: Wow this is great. I'm looking into using PDO, but for now, this will definitely help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ok I hate PDO too, "my own code is my own risk, while others code is also your own risk". Anyway, if you will use this script without any cleaner I'm sure you will make your DB explode. you may want to take a look at others mysql database connection classes before starting your own:

*[take a look here](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=mysql%20connection&x=0&y=0&go_search=1)*

Comment: "my own code is my own risk, while others code is also your own risk" < so do you write your own OS, web-server, database-server, scripting language interpreter, too?

Comment: I don't know why you guys so sensitive about this matter! there are thousand of thousand of scripts around the world using php and mysql without PDO .. what is the big idea here? if I want to do my own class that mean like I want to have my own OS? ok I agree - if I could do write hole OS system - then I will :))

Comment: not being sensitive - but not using PDO just because you didn't write the library is a pretty poor reason. Now - if it was proven to be badly written or insecure, then that would be a good reason.